# Assembly mov segments

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Are the following assumptions correct in regards to segment usage?

```
mov ax, [bp] ; Uses SS?
mov ax, disp[bp]; Uses SS?
mov ax, [bp+10h]; Uses SS?
mov ax, [bx+10h]; Uses DS?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks right:

> By default BX, SI and DI registers work with DS segment register; BP
> and SP work with SS segment register.

[*A reference source*.](http://www.compeng.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_registers/8086_registers.html)